# issue with a javascript object to update mongodb with node red

Tags: javascript, node-red

What am I doing wrong?

In the function below I have to adjust newMsg.payload.

Exactly, I want to adjust day.0.0.temperature/humidity: the first 0 is the placeholder for the hours and the second 0 is for the minutes.
I can get hours/minutes as I need, the problem is to replace them.

```
var newMsg = {};
newMsg.collection = 'collection_name';
newMsg.operation  = 'update';
newMsg.payload    =    { "account" : "marco",
     "sensorId" : "1"
   },
   { '$set': { "day.0.0.temperature": 11 ,
                "day.0.0.humidity": 11 }
   },
   { upsert: true, multi: false
   };
```

This is what I tried and it doesn't work.

```
var newMsg = {};
newMsg.collection = 'collection_name';
newMsg.operation  = 'update';
newMsg.payload    =    { "account" : "marco",
     "sensorId" : "1"
   },
   { '$set': { "day." + h + "." + m + ".temperature": 11 ,
                "day." + h + "." + m + ".humidity": 11 }
   },
   { upsert: true, multi: false
   };
```

Thanks

Comment: You've not told us in what way the second set of code doesn't work. Also which mongodb node are you using there are at least 2

Answer (score 0):

this is how I made it working.

```
  { "\'$set\'": { "day" :  { [h] : { [m] : { "temperature" : msg.data.temperature } } },
                    "day" : { [h] : { [m] :{ "humidity" : msg.data.humidity } } }
}
```

Regards